# Create a custom happstack response code

Tags: haskell, happstack

I have been trying to create a custom `happstack` response the `405 "Method not allowed"` so if someone calls the `API` with a `POST` or `PUT` method they will get this response. I am new to `happstack`. Any ideas how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the [**`ok :: (FilterMonad Response m) => a -> m a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/happstack-server-7.5.1/docs/Happstack-Server-Response.html) function is implemented as [[src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/happstack-server-7.5.1/docs/src/Happstack-Server-Response.html#ok):

> ```
> ok :: (FilterMonad Response m) => a -> m a
> ok = resp 200
> ```

So it is the same way like you would write an `ok` response, except that you should use [**`resp :: (FilterMonad Response m) => Int -> b -> m b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/happstack-server-7.5.1/docs/Happstack-Server-Response.html#v:resp) with a custom return code.

For example:

```
resp 405 "Method not allowed"
```

So we can for example block `PUT` and `POST` requests with something like:

```
main :: IO ()
main = simpleHTTP nullConf $ msum
         [ do method GET
              ok $ "This is allowed.\n"
         , do method PUT
              (resp 405) $ "Method not allowed"
         , do method POST
              (resp 405) $ "Method not allowed"
         ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response , I am getting this error  -- 
In the second argument of ‘resp’, namely ‘"Method not allowed"’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: resp 405 "Method not allowed"
      In the expression:
        do { method PUT;
             resp 405 "Method not allowed" } --
I tried to find what is wrong but no luck .

Comment: Hmm.. I think I forgot some brackets. Edited the answer.

Comment: I am getting the same error -- • No instance for (Data.String.IsString Response)
        arising from the literal ‘"Method not allowed"’
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘"Method not allowed"’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: (resp 405) $ "Method not allowed"
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘do { method [PUT, POST];
              (resp 405) $ "Method not allowed" }’  --

Comment: Here you include `PUT` and `POST` in the same list?

Comment: Yeah sorry wrong copy this is the one --  No instance for (Data.String.IsString Response)
        arising from the literal ‘"Method not allowed"’
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘"Method not allowed"’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: (resp 405) $ "Method not allowed"
      In the expression:
        do { method PUT;
             (resp 405) $ "Method not allowed" }

Comment: Are the there any other handlers in your list that work with a response instead of a string literal?

Comment: @ib1: in that case you need to construct as message something of the same type as the other handlers.

Comment: No there are not.